# Responsive Owl Carousel and hide controls

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Can someone help me with Owl Carousel? 
I need each item to show 1 image only at the whole screen. Also I need to hide the dot controls. It should be like a **"image background slide".**

Also, what about texts on each slide? I should insert them into the same `<div>` as the image on the `<div class="owl-carousel">` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [options documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html)..
For example..

to remove the "dots" you add {dots: false} to your options.

for only one slide you can add {items: 1} to your options.

And so on.

Comment: Thank you! I were using an older version of owl carousel. The {dots: false} option is available only in the last update. That's why it wasn't working for me.